# Angular 17 - SSR Standalone - Routing FactoryProvider with async - NG04014

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-providers, angular-standalone-components, angular-ssr

### Introduction

Hello, I'm trying to configure my angular router and pass it different routes depending on whether or not we are authenticated.

Here is my code to do this:

##### app.routes.ts

```js
export const authenticatedRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: DashboardPage,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'test'
  }
];

export const unauthenticatedRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    component: HomePage,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'test'
  }
];

export const provideRoutes = () => {
  const provider: Provider[] = [{
    provide: ROUTES,
    useFactory: async (oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) => {
      const { isAuthenticated } = await firstValueFrom(oidcSecurityService.checkAuth())
      if (isAuthenticated) return authenticatedRoutes
      return unauthenticatedRoutes
    },
    multi: true
  }]
  return makeEnvironmentProviders(provider)
}
```

##### app.config.ts

```js
import { provideRoutes } from '@/configurations'

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRoutes(),
    // others providers...
  ]
};
```

### Research

When I run `"ng build --watch --configuration development"`, I got this error

**An unhandled exception occurred: NG04014: Invalid configuration of route ''. One of the following must be provided: component, loadComponent, redirectTo, children or loadChildren**

The problem comes from the async factory, this code works:

```js
export const provideRoutes = () => {
  const provider: Provider[] = [{
    provide: ROUTES,
    useFactory: () => {
      return unauthenticatedRoutes
    },
    multi: true
  }]
  return makeEnvironmentProviders(provider)
}
```

But I have no idea how to solve this problem. Do you know what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous providers are not supported by Angular ([see issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279)).

You're probably looking for [route guards](https://angular.dev/guide/routing/common-router-tasks#preventing-unauthorized-access), and more specifically : `CanActivate`

Your guard

```
export const yourGuardFunction: CanActivateFn = (
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
      // your  logic goes here
  }
```

Your route:

```
{
  path: '/your-path',
  component: YourComponent,
  canActivate: [yourGuardFunction],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **@Matthieu Riegler**, I'm following up your message here, I found this solution with the guard canMatch:

```js
const authGuard: CanMatchFn = async () => {
  const oidcSecurityService = inject(OidcSecurityService)
  const { isAuthenticated } = await firstValueFrom(oidcSecurityService.checkAuth())
  return isAuthenticated
}

export const authenticatedRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardPage
  }
];

export const unauthenticatedRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
];

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: authenticatedRoutes,
    canMatch: [authGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    children: unauthenticatedRoutes
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }
]
```